# Failed to connect to server:port in 15000ms

Tags: node.js, sql-server

I have this code

```
import sql from "mssql";
import env from "./config/env";

const sqlConfig = {
  user: env.DB_USER,
  password: env.DB_PWD,
  database: env.DB_NAME,
  server: env.DB_SERVER,
  port: env.DB_PORT,
  pool: {
    max: 10,
    min: 0,
    idleTimeoutMillis: 30000,
  },
  options: {
    //encrypt: true, // for azure
    trustServerCertificate: true, // change to true for local dev / self-signed certs
  },
};

const pool = new sql.ConnectionPool(sqlConfig);
const poolConnect = pool.connect();

pool.on("error", (err) => {
  console.log(err);
});

export const runQuery = async (query: string) => {
    await poolConnect; // ensures that the pool has been created
    const request = pool.request();
    const result = await request.query(query);
    return result?.recordset || [];
};
```

which I think it leads to this exception:

```
(node:11688) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ConnectionError: Failed to connect to server:port in 15000ms
    at ...\node_modules\mssql\lib\tedious\connection-pool.js:71:17
    at Connection.onConnect (...\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1043:9)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:482:26)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:375:28)
    at Connection.emit (...\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1071:18)
    at Connection.connectTimeout (...\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1530:10)
    at Timeout._onTimeout (...\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1475:12)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:557:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:500:7)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:11688) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:11688) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I modified the exception to hide server IP, port and paths.
I have two node projects that connects to the same database with the same credentials, one works, one gives the exception above. The projects are both developed with node 14.17 and the dependency `mssql: ^7.2.1`

I tried to clean npm cache and reinstall all but it doesn't work.
I read all the related questions but I can't find a solution.

Comment: Is the failing project running inside a Docker container (or a Dev Container inside VS Code)? Is `env.DB_SERVER` set to `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` or `::1`?

Comment: thanks @AlwaysLearning, the `env.DB_SERVER` is setted to the IP of the network machine where the database is placed. If I put a `console.log` before the pool creation, logging all the `env.DB_*` variables, everything is setted correctly. I'm using VS Code, but the error appears even if I execute `npm run start` from the windows powershell.

Comment: By everything you've reported, especially considering another app on the same development machine successfully using the same library versions and connection details, then it should just work. I would suggest checking your environment file very carefully (probably with a hex editor) to make sure that the `server` and `port` variables in particular do not contain any non-printable control characters. Make sure that `server` is only a valid IP address, a host name, or a fully-qualified domain name (i.e.: it doesn't contain a backslash-delimited instance name).

Comment: I moved from something like

`const env = {
  DB_USER: process.env.DB_USER || "username"
};
export default env`

without a `.env` file, to something like:

`const env = {
  DB_USER: process.env.DB_USER
};
export default env`

with the new `.env` file written manually, but nothing changes. 
The `console.log` before the pool creation logs correct credentials